# protractor property of argument "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to write protractor tests where in some tests XMLHttpRequest needs to be mocked out. I'm trying to do this by passing an imported [`xhr-moc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr-mock) to the browser using `executeScript`. The instance is passed to the browser but methods become uncallable as they become `string` instances.

E.g.:

```
it('demo', function() {
    var x = mock;
        browser.executeScript(function (mock) {
            mock.setup()
    }, mock)
});
```

Output:

```
...
Failed: unknown error: mock.setup is not a function
...
```

When further investigating:

```
it('demo', function() {
    console.log('from spec: ', typeof mock.setup)

    browser.executeScript(function (mock) {
        return typeof mock.setup
    }, mock)
    .then(function(output) {
        console.log('from browser:', output)
    });
});
```

Output:

```
...
Started
from spec:  function
from browser: string
.
...
```

Is there a a sane way to pass this object to the browser without having the methods converted to strings?

Or can I serialize the object before sending and deserialize the object in the script to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code.

```
it('demo', function() {
var x = mock;
    browser.executeScript(function (arguments[0]) {
        arguments[0].setup()
}, mock)
```

});

The parameters that you are passing to executeScript method should be accessed using arguments array.and you can also pass any number of arguments and access it using the index.